# They grew up in the Sudan; hence their interest in Nubian art

Tags: adverbs, adverbials

[thefreedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hence):

> *They grew up in the Sudan; hence their interest in Nubian art*.

Am I right that?:

- "*Hence*" is an adverb.
- "*Hence*" is the head of the adverbial phrase "*Hence their interest in Nubian art*".
- "*Hence their interest in Nubian art*" functions as a supplement.
- "*They grew up in the Sudan*" is the anchor of the supplement.

Thanks!

Comment: The role of 'hence' here is so far from the central adverbial role (try substituting a real adverb here) that I can't accept the labelling. CGEL lists it among their dustbin class 'prepositions', but perhaps their descriptor 'impure connectives' should be promoted to POS.